# How does IE encoding auto-select works?

Tags: internet-explorer, character-encoding

If I use IE to open a webpage whose content-type charset is not set explicitly. And also assume the web server doesn't add charset value in HTTP response header. So, in this situation, what criteria does IE takes to determine the encoding when rendering webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interent Explorer relies upon a component called "MLANG" from the Windows Globalization team to attempt to "sniff" the bytes returned by the server to determine what character set is likely in use.

This code is not documented, but uses frequency analysis and information about the current user's locale to attempt to "guess" what codepage the server used.

Pages should *always* set a proper charset in order to avoid this sniffing, which can result in unpredictable results (e.g. for instance, the heuristic can return different results when run on a Japanese machine vs. on a US-English machine).